# Sugestões de alterações para as opções de sinalização

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Uma das opções de sinalização das quais dispomos atualmente é a seguinte:

> **Deveria ser fechada**
>   Esta pergunta é muito ampla, incompleta, difícil de entender, depende de opiniões ou não tem a ver com programação, como descrito na central de ajuda. É improvável que uma edição consiga resolver o problema.

Acho que essa opção pode deixar de ser exibida para aqueles usuários que já têm o privilégio de votar para fechar. Os votos para fechamento são mais precisos com relação à necessidade de se fechar a pergunta.

---

Outra alteração que poderia ser feita. Hoje vi um post no qual o autor citou um site e pôs suas credenciais de acesso na pergunta. Não vou identificar a pergunta, mas já sinalizei para que algo seja feito - simplesmente editar não removeria as credenciais do histórico de edição.

Para sinalizar, usei a seguinte opção:

> **Precisa de atenção dos moderadores**
>   Há um outro problema que precisa de intervenção dos moderadores. Descreva detalhadamente o problema.

Mas só a utilizei por falta de opção melhor. Acho que poderíamos ter uma do tipo:

> **Contém informação sensível**
>   Esta pergunta contém credenciais de acesso a um sistema ou outras informações sigilosas. Apenas editá-la ainda mantém as informações sigilosas no histórico de edição. É necessário intervenção da moderação para que essas informações sejam removidas de forma definitiva do site.

Comment: O **deveria ser fechada** abre a janela de votos para fechar. No segundo caso, eu acho interessante, mas são poucas vezes que isso acontece. Acho que ia só ocupar espaço, tendo em vista que o **precisa de atenção dos moderadores** já faz bem o papel.

Comment: Eu gosto da idéia, mas não consigo visualizar isto entrando na lista de prioridades do site. Provavelmente seria ótimo se pudesse ser implementado como "option sugar"™ que simplesmente fizesse o mesmo que o "precisa de atenção dos moderadores", mas já com texto preenchido (a finalidade da opção extra seria para direcionar o "sinalizante" pela opção mais correta, e não para criar um novo contexto)

Comment: Quando há informação sensível eu apenas apago ou substituo por dados fictícios. Não vejo necessidade em sinalizar se temos opção de editar. Numa ocasião tive que sinalizar pois não continha dados sensíveis de forma explícita mas de forma indireta era possível conseguir obter dados de cartões de crédito de um site que postaram aqui. Eu preferi não editar para não ficar invasivo e sinalizei. Mas a sinalização foi rejeitada com uma certa grosseria dizendo para eu parar de sinalizar se não for algo útil.. Depois disso, não ligo para mais nada. Se postarem senha, etc, azar de quem postou.

Comment: @DanielOmine eu reforço o que disse, apenas editar o post não remove as informações sensíveis. Você pode sempre ver as informações no histórico de edição.

Comment: Claro que editar não é "a solução", mas fica menos exposto. A maioria nem se dá ao trabalho de ver o histórico e nem faz sentido alguém querer ir no histórico vasculhar se no post principal não houver nada que o "encoraje" a tal. Repetindo, não protege 100% mas evita maiores chances de um ato ilícito. E deixando claro mais uma vez, não estou colocando isso numa posição contrária ao que propõe. Quanto ao que propôs, tenho mesma opinião descrita pelo @Bacco, logo acima. Por isso acho que editar os dados sensíveis é o meio mais simples dos quais temos acesso. Cada um faz de boa vontade...